# Is there any hotkey to exit from shadow?

Tags: rdp, windows-server-2016

How can I close shadow window without using mouse? Is there any hotkey? My aims is to avoid move user mouse cursor, when I've decided to exit.
In Windows 2008 R2 I was able to use `Ctrl + *`  or another hotkey which I choiced when entered to shadow.

Comment: Is this about RDP?

Comment: @Jonathan Yes, shadow of an user RDP ssession

Comment: Funny enough, Microsoft states `CTRL+* (numpad)` is still the way to go in Server 2016: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shadow

Answer (score 2):

I found this which should help you with your problem:

One Solution is to use the numpad if you have one:

```
  Ctrl+NP*
```

The other solution is:

Turn off windows key combination using registry to Disable Windows Key combination for mstsc.exe ( RDP )

Open Registry and go to:

```
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\DefaultUserConfiguration

  Shadow=1
```

Change Binary Value to:

```
  Shadow=0
```

Now windows shortcut keys will work with Winkey like to Open Explorer: "Winkey + E "

So you can now make other key combinations work as they should.

Idea found here: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26622927/Change-finish-hotkey-for-command-line-shadow-of-a-terminal-or-RDP-session.html

Comment: Please expand the answer to include the information in the link. Link-only answers will get down-voted.

Comment: OK, I am new could you explain how I should format this type of information.

Comment: Hi, you can paste the solution, quote it and give the source, its a best way to do it, as link only answer can die in age, and expertexchange sometime block to see the answer when not a members too, thus not a reliable link only answer. To do so you can click edit and modify your answer

Comment: Read it, understand it, and put it in your own words.